# Image displays properly in chrome but not in firefox or IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, internet-explorer, html, firefox

So in an html.erb document I have a table with in it and in that table is an image scaled to the size of the column like so:

```
   <table width="900" border="0" align="center" valign="top">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="someimage.gif" width="35%" height="95%" /></td>
        <td>a whole bunch more html content here</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
```

It works fine in Chrome but for some reason when I load the page in either IE or Fire Fox it shows the image in its original size, not scaled to the size of the of the column like it should be. I tried removing the height and weight properties instead replacing them with some in line CSS like this:

```
    <img src="someimage.gif" style="height:95%;width:35%"/>
```

but again I encounter the same issue. Works fine in Chrome but not in the other two. Does anybody know what might be causing the compatibility issue and what I can do to fix or work around it?

Edit: I probably should have mentioned that I tried defining the size of the images both in an external CSS file using absolute and relative as arguments for the position, followed by pixel values for the size, then later, after removing that CSS code, in the height and width section of the HTML5 img tags. In both cases zooming in any browser screwed up the overall look of the site which was why I switched to using percent values.

Comment: You're missing a `t` in `heigh="95%"`; are you sure this is not the cause of the problem?

Comment: That was a typo in this post. Its not the problem in the actual code. Thanks for pointing that out though, I need to learn to proof read before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser cannot determine the width of columns until it has determined the (width of) its contents. And in your case the width of content depend of width of column. You'll get unexpected results depending on browser and depending on whether the image is present in the cache or not.

Specify a width and height for the column and you'll get the expected, consistent results. [See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yd55/1/).

Answer (score 0):

for firefox you could try css background size for example

```
<td>
    <div style="background: url(someimage.gif); background-size: 100% 100%; width: 35%; height: 95%;">
    </div>
</td>
```

**or you could try jQuery but your html would have to look like this**

```
 <table width="900" border="0" align="center" valign="top">
  <tr  class="image_tr">
    <td  class="image_td"><img class="image" src="someimage.gif"/></td>
    <td>a whole bunch more html content here</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

**now here is the jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var height_percent = $("table .image_tr").height() / 100;
    var width_percent = $("table .image_td").width() / 100;

    $(".image").height(height_percent * 95);
    $(".image").width(width_percent * 35)
});
```

Comment: `<style type="text/css">
  .imagestyle {
    width:35%;
    height:95%;
    padding-left:1px;
   }
</style>
.
.
.
<img src="someimage.gif" class="imagestyle"/>
.
.
.`

Same issue as before. Works in Chrome, not in FireFox or Internet Explorer. I do have have an external CSS file though. I'll try manipulating the image through that.

Comment: you could also replace the img tag and replace it width a div.  Look at my post now.

Answer (score 0):

You should try defining the width of the td's in the table, i find them often messing up in internet explorer :)

Answer (score 0):

All browsers scale the image, but the results differ, since the cell size varies. You can see this if you change `border="0"` to `border="1"`. Different browsers apply different column width allocation algorithms to tables, especially in tricky cases like this. You are requesting the image to be scaled to 35% of the available width, essentially the cell width, and the cell width in turn depends on the contents of the cell, among other things. Similar considerations apply to height.

To fix this, you need to specify the desired appearance in terms that do not depend on a particular table formatting algorithms of a specific browser.